Ubuntu 24.04 installation - Unable to set my hard drive for bootloader
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04. Since I have a windows partition, I chose the manual partitioning. I must choose a drive to install the bootloader. Two drives are listed: my hard drive and my usb stick. Obviously, I want to install the bootloader on the hard drive but it is grayed out and I can only select the USB (see image).
On my hard drive, there is a partition of 104Mo that I indicated I want to use as /boot with format VFAT. I thought maybe it was too small but even if I put a larger /boot VFAT partition, the hard drive is still grayed out... (I will also use sda6 as my root partition but when I set it does not change anything)
I installed several times ubuntu and it is the first time that I face this issue...  I have no idea what could be the problem.
Could you tell me how to fix it?
EDIT: As suggested by @user68186, deleting the root and swap partitions on the live USB using gparted before the installation made it possible to select my hardrive for the bootloader.

Edit adding the parted screenshot:


If I set a boot partition in ext4, the hard drive is still grayed out.

@user68186 I added the gparted screen

Do not mix /boot which must be Linux formatted with an ESP - efi system partition which must be FAT32 formatted. Most desktops do not need separate /boot partition.  Server type installs or those with full disk encryption (not dual boot) may need a /boot partition and the ESP for UEFI boot. Part of confusion may be that esp is mounted in /boot once installed. Since install is obsolete version and no directly way to update to another obsolete version, may be easier just to install 24.04 since no data to save. But once installed be sure to create backup procedure.

Backup your data
It look like you have a dual boot computer with Windows and Mint. You want to replace Mint with Ubuntu.
First, backup your personal data from the Mint OS partition into an external drive. When you install Ubuntu, all the personal files and folders in the /dev/sda6 will be lost. Second, back up your personal data from the Windows partition into an external drive.
Try Ubuntu and Gparted

Boot from the Ubuntu Live Installation USB, and choose the Try
Ubuntu option. If you have already started the installation process then cancel installation. You will be in the Ubuntu desktop.
Open Gparted and select the /dev/sda6. You may have to select the drive /dev/sda from the top right drop down menu first.
click on the Partition at the top menu, and click Delete.
Click on the Green arrow to "Apply all operations".
Optional, if you don't use hibernation: Select /dev/sda7 the swap partition. and delete it using the
partition menu. Ubuntu uses swap files by default. A separate swap partition is only needed for hibernation. Hibernation is turned off in Ubuntu by default.
Click on the Green arrow to "Apply all operations" again.

This will delete the /dev/sda6 partition containing Linux Mint for ever.

Close Gparted.

Install Ubuntu with default option
Click on the Install Ubuntu icon on the Live Ubuntu USB desktop to start the install process.
Select Ubuntu side by side Windows option. The installer will find the empty space you created where the /dev/sda6 was (and /dev/sda7 if you deleted it) and install Ubuntu there. You will get a chance to verify the partition location before you moving forward with the installation.
The installer will take care of the bootloader location. Part of the bootloader will go into the UEFI partition.
Hope this helps

Thank you for the detailed answer! I did not think of deleting the swap and root partitions... Since I was in a hurry, I managed to install ubuntu 23.03 instead with the legacy installer which worked as I was used to. Since there is no legacy installer started from the 24.04 I will have to use your approach next time. Thanks again

@Zach I assume you mean Ubuntu 23.04, as there is no 23.03. If so, note that 23.04 and 23.10 have both reached the end of life and are not supported any more. That means: 1. Future questions about it will be off topic here. 2. There will be no security and other updates. 3. Upgrading to a more recent version will be difficult.

Yes I meant 23.04 indeed. I will try to upgrade to the 24.04 from 23.04 in that case

The upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 is discontinued so I tried again to install the 24.04. Deleting the swap and root partitions made it possible for me to select my hardrive as a bootloader! Thanks again.
